# How do I create trivial customized field types in Django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to make some types in Django that map to standard Django types.  The [custom model field documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#howto-custom-model-fields) goes into complicated cases; I just want to store a basic Django type from a class with a bunch of handy methods.

For example, if I were storing playing cards, I want something like:

```
class Card(object):
    """ A playing card.  """
    def as_number(self):
        """ returns a number from 1 (Ace of Clubs) and 52 (King of Spades)."""
        return self.number + self.suit_rank() * 13
    def __unicode(self): ...
    def is_highest(self, other_cards, trump=None):...
    def __init__(self, number, suit):  ...
     ...
```

I want my models to have something like:

```
class my_game(models.Model):
    ante = models.IntegerField()
    bonus_card = Card()   # Really stored as an models.IntegerField()
    ....
```

I'm expecting the answer will look like inheriting from the correct type, adding some specially named get/store fields for card, and renaming **init**().  Does anyone have sample code or better documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do this with a subclass of Django's PositiveIntegerField:

```
from django.db import models

class Card(object):
    """The ``Card`` class you described."""
    ...

class CardField(models.PositiveIntegerField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value):
        """Return the ``int`` equivalent of ``value``."""
        if value is None: return None
        try:
            int_value = value.as_number()
        except AttributeError:
            int_value = int(value)
        return int_value

    def to_python(self, value):
        """Return the ``Card`` equivalent of ``value``."""
        if value is None or isinstance(value, Card):
            return value
        return Card(int(value))
```

The `get_db_prep_value` method is responsible for converting `value` into something suitable for interacting with the database, in this case either an `int` or `None`.

The `to_python` method does the reverse, converting `value` into a `Card`.  Just like before, you'll need to handle the possibility of `None` as a value.  Using the `SubfieldBase` ensures that `to_python` is called every time a value is assigned to the field.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you do something like the following?

```
class Card(models.Model):
    """ A playing card.  """
    self.suit = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    self.rank = models.PositiveIntegerField( choices=SUIT_CHOICES )
    def as_number(self):
        """ returns a number from 1 (Ace of Clubs) and 52 (King of Spades)."""
        return self.number + self.suit * 13
    def __unicode__(self):
        return ...
    def is_highest(self, other_cards, trump=None):...
```

Certainly, this is quite simple, and fits comfortably with what Django does naturally.

Comment: This only works in the trivial case, creates a new table to manage, and burns about 100x more storage and computation time.   Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: Don't know what "trivial case" means, since this always works.  The integer uses 52*4 bytes, this uses 100*52*4 = 21K bytes, still nothing.  And you don't manage the tables, Django does.  Don't see the actual problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be afraid to adapt the model classes in Django to your own needs. There's nothing magical about them. And I guess this is the Right Place for this code: In the model.